# JavaScript RegEx: How to create a RegEx pattern using a specific value from a Variable?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this variable:

```
var search = "dummy";
var replace = "<strong>" + search + "</strong>";
var contents = "my contents are here and this dummy value should be bolded...";

contents.replace(/search/gi, replace);
```

So, How can I set this "search" variable under my RegEx pattern, followed with /gi settings for my match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
new RegExp('yourSearchHere', 'gi');
```

you should also be aware of the fact, that you have to escape certain sequences. Btw. you have to double escape these when you're constructing a regex like this (new RegExp('\\n') -> matches \n)

Comment: this would fail if we have input as \\\

Answer (score 3):

You can also create a regular expression using the RegExp object:

```
search = "dummy";
x = new RegExp(search,"gi");

var search = "dummy";
var replace = "<strong>" + search + "</strong>";
var contents = "my contents are here and this dummy value should be bolded...";
window.alert(contents.replace(x, replace));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YhqjY/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html):
The $1 is remembering what you matched with the regular expression. It does this because the word you are searching for is placed inside round brackets which form a capturing group.

```
var contents = "my contents are here and this dummy value should be bolded...";


function makeStronger( word, str ) {
    var rxp = new RegExp( '(' + word +')', 'gi' );
    return str.replace( rxp, '<strong>$1<\/strong>' );
}

console.log( makeStronger( 'dummy', contents ) );
// my contents are here and this <strong>dummy</strong> value should be bolded...
```